# How to switch/override the variable 'aspxerrorpath'?

Tags: asp.net

I am getting the problem of aspxerrorpath.

I dont want asp.net to validate this variable, even when I have custom page error enabled. If I write something like `https://...../asd.aspx?aspxerrorpath=<script>alert(7);</script>` it throws an error and forward me to the aspx error page by default and not to one of my pre-defined custom error pages. Why? How can I override the aspxerrorpath behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `validateRequest="false"` to the page that is handling the error (the one referenced in `<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx">`)